# Is there a library in django that can pull docstrings to create documentation?

Tags: django, documentation

there appears to be a library to generate docs from docstrings but the documentation will only be available in the django admin interface.

Is there a library that will pull the docstrings and dump them in a text, word or excel file?

Comment: Hint : Django is a Python framework, so all standard Python tools are available.

Comment: yup sorry I got impatient googling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) is often used in Python to generate HTML documentation from your code. It can generate plain text files. Or if you want to generate Word Documents (docx), you could try https://github.com/mherkazandjian/docxsphinx (although I haven't used it before).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, another option which is very simplistic is [pycco](https://realpython.com/generating-code-documentation-with-pycco/)